# How to plot dates in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart for my website that takes a year's worth of dates (entries for each day), and then plots it on the graph.

I tried writing a function that makes a list of all dates in that v=certain range in the format of

```
"date1", "date2", "date3", ...
```

and then places that variable string into the series of chart.js

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]
```

When I have it like code above, it will produce the graph. But I need it to be dynamic, so I have functions that produce the dates and data. But when calling those functions into the variable linechartData, the chart does not work.

```
var lineChartData = {
    labels: [genDates()],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [genData()]
        },
```

This code directly above will not work.

If any one has any suggestions on how to plot the data, please post below.

The genData method just generates random numbers

```
 function gendata() {
     var i = 0;
     var data = "";
     while (i < 365) {
         data = data + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + ", ";
         i = i + 1;
     }
     return data;
 }
```

gendate method

```
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = startDate;
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    }
    dates = "";
    for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
        date = date + dateArray[i] + ", ";
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an implementation for `genDates` and `getData`?

Comment: Added those methods to the questions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there's a type mismatch at **genDates**. The labels array will evaluate as an array with a single string in it unlike in your original example. To work around this you could return an array directly and remove the wrapping array from your chart definition.

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding what you are describing. Can you explain it further?

Comment: @jmurphy1267 Your `[genDates()]` evaluates as `['January, February, ...']`. Not as an array of multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var areaChartData = {
labels: labelsnuevos(productos),
   // here goes my dataset
};

function labelsnuevos(productos)
{
    var labels = [];

    $.each(productos, function(key, value) {
        var lab = value.nombre;
        labels.push(lab);
    });
    return labels;
}
```

I have productos instead of dates, but you need to pass your "dates" to a variable, in this case my variable I sproductos, then with foreach you take and push its value.